# Styling the placeholder of an input, how can I do this?

Tags: css, html, input, placeholder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

For example, I have this:

```
<input type='search' placeholder='Search' name='q' />
```

How can I style the placeholder with CSS? By default it's gray, but I'd like it to be black. Do I have to use JavaScript instead?

Comment: so apparently, this has been asked. several times. But still a good question for someone who loves stackoverflow, but behind on everything html5 has to offer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 14, accepted):

no standard way, and not every browser supports place holder yet.

Something like this should do it.:

```
/* prefix with input if you want, but this will catch input and texatrea */
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {  color: #000;}
  :-moz-placeholder { color: #000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHG46/

if you want old and new browsers to support placeholder (IE6-9) there appears to be a jquery plugin(s), here is one,
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin
however, I have not used it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[placeholder="Search"]
{
color: red
}
```

Comment: That only colors inputs with that placeholder red, not the placeholders themselves.

Comment: This will style the *entered* text in any input that has the placeholder "Search", but it won't style the placeholder text itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css

Comment: lol. Dont even know the placeholder attribute. Should have made comments, rather than answers. Downvotes welcomed!